# How can I do an array of object of my class (with inheritance of another custom class)?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, class

I have to do for homework this little program:

> The program have to manage an agency of toys. The following lines are the specifics:

> 1. Toys must have a unique code, a name, a category (that can have this value: car, babydoll, electronic toy, robot, peluche, boardgame), price;
>    2. The lots must have a unique code, the list of toys that are inserted in the lot, the number of the lot-type now available, data production;
>    3. Toys must be stored in a text file called 'toys.txt', while lots must be stored in a size-10.000 array;

How can I implement the second part of point [3]?

I have implemented a class called Toy with this field:

- `int code`
- `string name`
- `enum category {car, ....}`
- `double price`

After that, I have implemented a second class called Lot with this field:

- `int code`
- `int numberOfLotAvaiable`
- `string data`
- `Toy toys`

"lots must be stored in a size-10.000 array" Do I have to add a field in class Lot with an array? Or Do I have to do an array of type Lot in the Main method? Even, Do I have to do another class?

Comment: Yes, when the assignment is "lots must be storaged in an size-10.000 array" they are saying the array contains Lots, not that a Lot contains an array. You want an array of Lot objects (just like Gjeltema's answer), not a Lot that contains an array.

Hmmm. This isn't even a programming question. It's a reading question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem statement is telling you to store the `Lot`s in an array of size 10.000, like so:

```
Lot[] myLots = new Lot[10000];
```

This question would better be directed to your professor or TA though.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your annoyance about my basic question. My exam concerns only C lenguage. My professor talked about .NET structure and some basic elements of C # but he said that for a better grade we will have to study C # as self-taught person and this is what I am doing.

Comment: @Cesarini.Walter I wasn't annoyed, I was just trying to ensure you go to the correct place to get your question fully answered.  If my post answered your question, then feel free to mark it as "answered" by clicking the green checkmark to the left of my post.  Best of luck!